# Run a download manager task in android using executor

Tags: android, executorservice, android-download-manager, executor

I am trying to implement downloadmanager in Browser2 aosp code. I have implemented the code to start the download manager service using executor but I need to close the executor after the download finishes. How can I perform that as many files might be downloading it.

Code I have created.

```
       webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) { 
                downloadFileAsync(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType); 
            } 
        });
```

```
    private void downloadFileAsync (String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType) { 
        ExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
        Runnable backgroundRunnable = new Runnable(){ 
        @Override 
        public void run(){ 
           try { 
               String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url); 
               String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType); 
               DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)) 
                       .setMimeType(mimeType) 
                       .addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies) 
                       .addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent) 
                       .setTitle(fileName) 
                       .setDescription("Downloadg") 
                       .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName) 
                       .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); 
               DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
               dm.enqueue(request); 
               } catch (Exception e){ 
                   Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage()); 
               } 
           } 
        }; 
        mExecutor.execute(backgroundRunnable); 
    }
```

Comment: DownloadManager runs already async. So no need to use threads or executors.

Comment: @blackapps But isn't async deprecated from API level 30.

Comment: AsyncTask? What has that to do with this?

Comment: @blackapps You meant to say DownloadManager works asynchronously, right? 
So it means that the DownloadManager works in background and does not affect the thread from which it is called ?

Comment: Yes. And a little try will confirm that.